# Preventing update rollback when exception occurs in CRM 2011 Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Given that the existing OrganizationServiceContext for a Plugin is performs updates in the current SQL transaction context (assuming pre or post validation event),  is there an efficient way to update a separate entity outside this transaction/context?

The goal is to avoid rollback of updates on a different entity (other than the Plugin target entity) when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new IOrganizationService rather than use OrganizationServiceContext.

Check this [example](http://crmtidbits.blogspot.pt/2014/02/bypass-plug-in-transaction-to-log.html).

Comment: Thank you for the link! But the article describes that creating a new IOrganizationService was the old way of doing it. The new way, described in the article, is by using the 'ExecuteMultipleRequest' and its 'ContinueOnError = true' setting.